# Dismiss default card presentation (.automatic) with animation Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

On apps using iOS 13, there is an option for ViewControllers to be shown as cards displayed on screen, or .automatic, that can be dismissed by a swipe. Adding a cancellation button, though, may dismiss the page, but, it does not include the animation of dismissing the card. Is there a way to add this programmatically?

This is my code, which is currently crashing the app:

```
 @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let detailVC = home()
        present(detailVC, animated: true)
        
    }
```

If I just add a segue to a button, the animation is just the page popping over, not dismissing as if you were swiping. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)       
}
```

What you're doing is preventing a new vc on an already presented modal.
What you actually want is to dismiss the currently presented modal.

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss